# Merge and Sort two Eloquent Collections?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've two Collections and I want merge it to one variable (of course, with ordering by one collumn - `created_at`). How Can I do that?

My Controllers looks that:

```
$replies = Ticket::with('replies', 'replies.user')->find($id);
$logs = DB::table('logs_ticket')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'mod_id')
        ->where('ticket_id', '=', $id)
        ->select('users.username', 'logs_ticket.created_at', 'action')
        ->get();
```

My Output looks for example:

Replies:

```
ID | ticket_id | username | message | created_at
1  | 1         | somebody | asdfghj | 2014-04-12 12:12:12
2  | 1         | somebody | qwertyi | 2014-04-14 12:11:10
```

Logs:

```
ID | ticket_id | username | action | created_at
1  | 1         | somebody | close  | 2014-04-13 12:12:14
2  | 1         | somebody |  open  | 2014-04-14 14:15:10
```

And I want something like this:

```
ticket_id | table | username | message | created_at
1         |replies| somebody | asdfghj | 2014-04-12 12:12:12
1         | logs  | somebody |  close  | 2014-04-13 12:12:14
1         | logs  | somebody |  open   | 2014-04-14 11:15:10
1         |replies| somebody | qwertyi | 2014-04-14 12:11:10
```

EDIT:

My Ticket Model looks that:

```
<?php

class Ticket extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tickets';

    public function replies() {
        return $this->hasMany('TicketReply')->orderBy('ticketreplies.created_at', 'desc');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: DB::table returns array of stdObjects thus the results will be inconsistent or will need conversion to Eloquent Collection/Model. Paste your models with relations to get your answer with a better way

Comment: @deczo I added Ticket model.

Comment: Ticket Logs doesn't have model.

Comment: Then are logs simply additional data on the pivot table linking users and tickets?

Comment: have a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255845/laravel-5-1-sorting-merged-eloquent-collections

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're not going to be able to get exactly what you want easily.

In general, merging should be easy with a `$collection->merge($otherCollection);`, and sort with `$collection->sort();`. However, the merge won't work the way you want it to due to not having unique IDs, and the 'table' column that you want, you'll have to make happen manually.

Also they are actually both going to be collections of different types *I think* (the one being based on an `Eloquent\Model` will be `Eloquent\Collection`, and the other being a standard `Collection`), which may cause its own issues. As such, I'd suggest using DB::table() for both, and augmenting your results with columns you can control.

As for the code to achieve that, I'm not sure as I don't do a lot of low-level DB work in Laravel, so don't know the best way to create the queries. Either way, just because it's looking like starting to be a pain to manage this with two queries and some PHP merging, I'd suggest doing it all in one DB query. It'll actually look neater and arguably be more maintainable:

The SQL you'll need is something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        `r`.`ticket_id`,
        'replies' AS `table`,
        `u`.`username`,
        `r`.`message`,
        `r`.`created_at`
    FROM `replies` AS `r`
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u`
        ON `r`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
    WHERE `r`.`ticket_id` = ?
) UNION (
    SELECT
        `l`.`ticket_id`,
        'logs' AS `table`,
        `u`.`username`,
        `l`.`action` AS `message`,
        `l`.`created_at`
    FROM `logs` AS `l`
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u`
        ON `l`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
    WHERE `l`.ticket_id` = ?
)
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

It's pretty self-explanatory: do the two queries, returning the same columns, `UNION` them and then sort that result set in MySQL. Hopefully it (or something similar, as I've had to guess your database structure) will work for you.

As for translating that into a Laravel `DB::`-style query, I guess that's up to you.

Answer (score 32):

A little workaround for your problem.

```
$posts = collect(Post::onlyTrashed()->get());
$comments = collect(Comment::onlyTrashed()->get());

$trash = $posts->merge($comments)->sortByDesc('deleted_at');
```

This way you can just merge them, even when there are duplicate ID's.

Comment: Inefficient, but does the job in a pinch!

Comment: Why does this work? All the collect() method does is create a new Collection?

Comment: Eloquent returns an `Eloquent Collection` and collect returns a normal `Collection`. A 'normal' collection has different methods then the `Eloquent Collection`.

Comment: Why is this inefficient? Is there a better way?

Comment: The above code hits the DB twice where as the chosen answer contains only 1 query with a few internal select queries. In general, you want to do the least amount of work to get the data you need.

In chosen answer connection to the DB is already formed and the work is being done inside of the DB vs. sending a query through the Post model, getting the results. Then sending another query through the Comment model, getting those results. Merging/Sorting through collection's methods which use several for/foreach loops under the hood (not a big hit to processing but still something to consider)

Comment: This approach is causing a lot of queries. But it's a solution

Comment: `Eloquent Collection` seems to have the method `merge` too. so no need to  use collect here. ( i am on 5.4 though)

Comment: The whole point of the solution is to not use a Eloquent Collection. Otherwise duplicate ID's will be removed from the collection.

Comment: Need to add ->values() at the end, otherwise the foreach loop will not show the sorted order.
$trash = $posts->merge($comments)->sortByDesc('deleted_at')->values();